# why contact record get deleted when we delete related account record whereas they have look-Up relationship

Tags: admin

why contact record get deleted when we delete related account record whereas they have look-Up relationship. than what is the mean of lookup

Comment: In a Lookup , the detail not suppose to be deleted when the parent is deleted. Be sure that the details are deleted to , maybe you don't see it in the list view but it is there . If you sure that it is deleted check if there are any rules or Process builder that deleted them .http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2015/10/difference-between-master-detail.html

Answer (score 1):

A number of the Lookup relationships between standard objects are just "special" and have properties of both Lookup and Master-Detail relationships. This is one of them.